# Succulent with thorny stems and orange four-petaled flowers

Tags: identification, houseplants, succulents

I just bought this plant but I don't know its name nor how to care for it.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Probably a variety of *Euphorbia milii* or [crown of thorns plant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphorbia_milii). Care is easy, just give it a little water now and again and avoid getting it wet. It is native to Madagascar, so will prefer warm conditions. The flower colour is quite variable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is clearly the succulent **Euphorbia Milii**.

From what I know this is a strong plant. The most important thing for it to thrive is to have long hours of **direct sun**. Behind a window would be OK, and maybe even better outside during summer.